# String ArrayList being ignored when saving/loading with SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying several things in order to save and load an ArrayList, and the most I can get saved/loaded is the final string within the arrayList. I've run out of ideas on what else to try:

```
    public void SaveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    saveGameList = new ArrayList<String>(gameList);

    for (int i = 0; i < gameList.size(); i++) {

        editor.putString(saveGameList.get(i), gameList.get(i));// THIS DOESN'T GET SAVED
        editor.putString(TEXT, saveGameList.get(i)); //THIS SAVES THE LAST THING IN THE ARRAYLIST
    }
    editor.apply();
}

public void LoadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Trying to load data from " + saveGameList.size() + " or from " + gameList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    loadText = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < saveGameList.size(); i++) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "am i called?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // THE ANSWER IS NO
        //loadText = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, null); // NOT NEEDED. WAS FOR A TEST
        gameList.add(sharedPreferences.getString(saveGameList.get(i), null));
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Done loading data?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    gamesListTextView.setText(loadText);
    gameList.add(loadText);
}
```

So, within the SaveData method I have a for loop which goes through every element within the gameList ArrayList, and the putString that is using the saveGameList ArrayList is trying to pass everything from the gameList over to saveGameList, both being String ArrayLists, which works. The second putString is passing the final element of the gameList into a TEXT variable. The TEXT variable is being saved, but not the saveGameList. So, when I load up the program, TEXT is being loaded, but saveGameList loads empty.

Then, within the LoadData method, the for loop is never called, because saveGameList always loads as empty, rather than with the strings I tried adding within the SaveData method. I feel like I'm very close to getting this to work, but there is something I'm missing in getting the elements within saveGameList saved. What I was thinking was that if putString requires a variable to store whatever I'm passing, i figured I can use each element within the ArrayList as those variables. This works when I use a Toast message to check each element, but not when saving. Anyone have anything that can guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` accept `Sets`. You could convert your List into a `HashSet` or something similar and store it like that. When your read it back, convert it into an `ArrayList`

```
//Retrieve the values
Set<String> set = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(saveGameList);
editor.putStringSet("key", set);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: At the moment it crashes when I try doing anything with the first set variable, the one with .getStringSet(), but this still helps a lot in moving in the right direction. Thank you! Edit: Nevermind, i got it working. Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for several hours.